# Add Autotext with OpenXML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

How can i save autotext objects in a sql database and write it back in a word template with `openxml sdk 2.5` with c#.

This is what am trying to do for the images:

```
foreach (DocumentBinaryPart relatedDocumentPart in AutotextContainer.RelatedDocumentParts.Where(x => x.Type == "ImagePart"))
{
    ImagePart imagePart = mainDocumentPart.GlossaryDocumentPart.AddImagePart(relatedDocumentPart.ImageType, relatedDocumentPart.relationshipid);

    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(relatedDocumentPart.Data))
        imagePart.FeedData(stream);

    mainDocumentPart.GlossaryDocumentPart.AddPart<ImagePart>(imagePart, relatedDocumentPart.relationshipid);
}
```

I try to save the autotext in this relateddocumentparts to save it in database...